# pip install packages from URL

Tags: keras, pip

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm an absolute beginner.
I wanted to install this to get rid of an error:

```
pip3 install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git -U
```

I'm not sure how to do that. I got this error when I tried to install on command prompt:

```
ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git 'C:\Users\Danush\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-vjgdo2yi'
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ERROR%3A+Cannot+find+command+git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is obvious in your output that git is not installed or the ENVIRONMENT variable is not set.

Make sure to install Git first, if its already installed,
Make sure the environment variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

From the command you are using, you are installing Keras. Instead of using git link, just type `pip install keras`. Keras is automatically installed with TensorFlow.
Here is the documentation of Keras:
https://pypi.org/project/Keras/

Answer (score -3):

You can not use pip commands in a url, you need to do this from a teminal window, you can do it a number of way the easiest is by git clone

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
```

or you could use

```
sudo wget https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git
```

or even with curl but why not just go to https://github.com/keras-team/keras.git and download the zip fomr github?

Comment: I believe that's not true. [_pip_ is able to use the local _git_ client to install from a _git_ repository](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git). But in this case, _pip_ is not able to find the _git_ binary.

Comment: You learn something new everyday. Just wouldnt even try this as there are better ways.